# Rotating text and aligning it in CSS?

Tags: css

What is the preferred solution to rotating then aligning text to the side of some content?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nVtpz/

```
<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #009;
    margin: 50px;
}
.text
{
    border: 1px solid #900;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
.image {
    border: 1px solid #090;
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="text">
        Text to rotate
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the text to be aligned next to the bottom left corner of the image (but not on top of the image, i.e. without float)

I guess I could use `position: relative; bottom: 0px` or something similar, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[I think that this is what you are going for](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/nVtpz/1/), but you can change the transform origin using `transform-origin` (with related vendor prefixes as needed).  This is situational, but in your case:

```
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: but the text now is flipped :>

Comment: @AndreaLigios cause you need to put all the `-browser-specifics`

Comment: @AndreaLigios oh, I thought that was what you wanted.  How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/nVtpz/2/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't think so... I mean, I did it (or never would have worked, I'm on FF), but the text is facing left instead of right, respect the example of OP

Comment: @ExplosionPills that is phun cause it's not even rotated :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios sometimes we're not here to serve the dessert, but to put the OP in the right direction

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I guess this is not one of that dessert times

Comment: Hmm didn't know about translateX(), though I wanted it on the left instead of right of the image:
http://jsfiddle.net/nVtpz/3/ - Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
          transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
          transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
.image img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    
  <div class="text">
    Text to rotate
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To rotate text simply:

```
.container {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: sideways;
}
```

Then set it in a CSS grid so it can track the viewport using `sticky` if you want it to move on scroll.